# Find keys with min difference in dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Say, I have this collection, it is generic dictionary

```
var items = new Dictionary<int, SomeData>
{
    { 1  , new SomeData() },
    { 5  , new SomeData() },
    { 23 , new SomeData() },
    { 22 , new SomeData() },
    { 2  , new SomeData() },
    { 7  , new SomeData() },
    { 59 , new SomeData() }
}
```

In this case min distance (difference) between keys = 1, for instance, between 23 and 22 or between 1 and 2

```
23 - 22 = 1 or 2 - 1 = 1
```

**Question :** how to find min difference between keys in generic Dictionary? Is there one line LINQ solution for this?

**Purpose :** If there are several matches then I need only one - the smallest, this is needed to fill missing keys (gaps) between items

Comment: This smells like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to calculate min between keys? And what would you expect to happen when there is more than one min which matches?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov : updated question with the purpose

Comment: LINQ is not always the answer for everything. Try and write a function that does this - it may be easier than you might think.

Comment: BTW you could use actual dictionary initializer instead of `x => y` which wouldn't compile...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer : mentioned collection is a pseudo code, I said that this is a dictionary just for the sake of simplicity, I know how to instantiate generic collections in .NET

Comment: @Andy So demonstrate it and use valid code. A dictionary initializer is the same effort than your invalid pseudo-code

Comment: @Andy Also, for me, it seems to be easier `{ "x", SomeData }` than `"x" => SomeData`. My first attemp to read your code was thinking you're adding delegates......................

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer : does it look better now?

Comment: @Andy Yeah, it's worth the effort!!

Comment: Now that your purpose is clearer (fill gaps in keys) I've edited my answer to actually solve your problem. Please take a look on my second edit or you'll have a non-working solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to do it by one line in LINQ but this is multiline solution for this problem.

```
         var items = new Dictionary<int, string>();
         items.Add(1, "SomeData");
         items.Add(5, "SomeData");
         items.Add(23, "SomeData");
         items.Add(22, "SomeData");
         items.Add(2, "SomeData");
         items.Add(7, "SomeData");
         items.Add(59, "SomeData"); 

         var sortedArray = items.Keys.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

         int minDistance = int.MaxValue;

         for (int i = 1; i < sortedArray.Length; i++)
         {
             var distance = Math.Abs(sortedArray[i] - sortedArray[i - 1]);
             if (distance < minDistance)
                 minDistance = distance;
         }

         Console.WriteLine(minDistance);
```

Comment: you should add either the low index (i - 1) or maybe use an ArraySegment<int> to keep the location (or  value directly) of the chosen key pair in case of several matches

Answer (score 2):

not sure Linq is the most appropriate but something (roughly) along this should work :

```
var smallestDiff = (from key1 in items.Keys
                    from key2 in items.Keys
                    where key1 != key2
                    group new { key1, key2 } by Math.Abs (key1 - key2) into grp
                    orderby grp.Key
                    from keyPair in grp
                    orderby keyPair.key1
                    select keyPair).FirstOrDefault ();
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, upvoted, although, this is going to be quite big collection and thus I do not want to iterate it over and over again, unfortunately this example contains too many of them

Comment: that's precisely why I think Linq is inappropriate ;)

Answer (score 2):

I won't give you a LinQ query because there already is an answer.
I know this is not what you are asking for, but I want to show you how to solve it in a very fast and easy to understand/maintain way, if performance and legibility is of any concern to you.

```
int[] keys;
int i, d, min;

keys = items.Keys.ToArray();
Array.Sort(keys); // leverage fastest possible implementation of sort

min = int.MaxValue;
for (i = 0; i < keys.Length - 1; i++)
{
  d = keys[i + 1] - key[i]; // d is always non-negative after sort
  if (d < min)
  {
    if (d == 2)
    {
      return 2; // minimum 1-gap already reached
    } else if (d > 2) // ignore non-gap
    {
      min = d;
    }
  }
}

return min; // min contains the minimum difference between keys
```

Because there is only one sort the performance of this non-LinQ solution performs pretty quick. **I don't say this is the best way**, but only that you should measure both solutions and compare performance.

**EDIT:** based on your purpose I've added this piece:

```
    if (d == 2)
    {
      return 2; // minimum 1-gap already reached
    } else if (d > 2) // ignore non-gap
    {
      min = d;
    }
```

Now what does this mean?

Say the **PROBABILITY** of having 1-gaps is high, it is probably faster to check at every change of `min` if you've reached that minimum gap. This may happen when you are 1% or 10% through the for loop, based on probability. So, for very large sets (say, above 1 million or 1 billion) and once you know the probability to expect, this probabilistic approach may give you huge performance gains.

On the contrary, for small sets or when the probability of 1-gaps is low, these extra CPU cycles are wasted and you are better off without that check.

As with very large databases (think of *probabilistic indexing*) probabilistic reasoning becomes relevant.

The problem is that you'll have to estimate beforehand if and when the probabilistic effect kicks in, and that's a pretty complex topic.

**EDIT 2:** a 1-gap actually has an index difference of `2`. Furthermore, and index difference of `1` is a non-gap (there is no gap to insert an index in between).

So the previous solution was simply wrong, because as soon as two indices are contiguous (say 34, 35) the minimum will be `1`, which is not a gap at all.

Because of this gap-problem the internal `if()` is necessary and at that point the overhead of the probabilistic approach is nullified. You'll be better off with the **correct** code and **probabilistic** approach!

Comment: Upvoted, but Oleg's answer was first, thus, all credits go to him

Comment: That's ok, you are free to decide who to up or down vote or what *moral* reasoning to apply. Still, look at the edit I've made it may be relevant for you :)

Comment: I like your idea with min gap, in general it would definitely improve performance, but in my case I have dates as a keys in format of "seconds after epoch", unix timestamp, and min step between them may vary, e.g. if items in dictionary are hours then min step between closest keys should be equal to 3600 seconds (1 hour), if items are days, then min step is 86400 seconds (1 day) and so on ...

Answer (score 1):

I think LINQ is simplest

First, making diff pair from your dictionary

```
var allPair = items.SelectMany((l) => items.Select((r) => new {l,r}).Where((pair) => l.Key != r.Key));
```

Then find the min of diff

```
allPair.OrderBy((pair) => Math.Abs(pair.l.Key - pair.r.Key)).FirstOrDefault();
```

But you may have multiple pair with same difference value, so you may need to use GroupBy before using OrderBy then handle the multiple pair by yourself

Comment: @Eminem : well, for those who are familiar with LINQ it really looks simple enough and concise, although, in terms of performance in this particular case it is better to stay with common loop

Comment: @Andy BTW, *performance* consideration is relative to the actual performance impact in your concrete use case...

Answer (score 1):

A one line solution not listed in answers:

```
items.Keys.OrderBy(x => x).Select(x => new { CurVal = x, MinDist = int.MaxValue }).Aggregate((ag, x) => new { CurVal = x.CurVal, MinDist = Math.Min(ag.MinDist, x.CurVal - ag.CurVal) }).MinDist
```